# EditForm Validate with Multiple Classes

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a razor EditForm page that it's model has several classes on it, each class has it's own data annotations. This form when submit must insert data to different tables. When I click the submit no validations are triggered.

```
<EditForm Model="@ViewModel.EditModel" OnSubmit="OnSubmit">

private void OnSubmit(EditContext context)
{
context.EnableDataAnnotationsValidation(); //Trying to force the validations
if(context.Validate()) //Always true
{
//Do stuff
}
}
```

As for the ViewModel it has a class named InformationSave that holds 5 different classes.

```
InformationSave EditModel { get; set; }
```

if the InformationSave.cs having

```
public TableA tablea { get; set; } = new TableA();
public TableB tablea { get; set; } = new TableB();
public TableC tablea { get; set; } = new TableC();
public TableD tablea { get; set; } = new TableD();
public TableE tablea { get; set; } = new TableE();
```

If I have a single class validation, for example, only TableA, then the validations do trigger, but not having multiple classes.

Comment: This isn't supported out of the box. But Microsoft added a experimental package to to complex object annotations. Personally I find it much easier to achieve this using FluentValidation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the nuget package
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.DataAnnotations.Validation
**(it's prerelease, keep that in mind!)**

Then in your razor file instead of `<DataAnnotationsValidator/>` you will use `<ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator/>`.

Finally, you will decorate your child classes like this:

```
[ValidateComplexType]
public TableA tablea { get; set; } = new TableA();

[ValidateComplexType]
public TableB tablea { get; set; } = new TableB();

...
```